# How do I update custom form Data

Tags: 7, forms

I have built a custom form in Drupal 7 it has three fields nid, uName, Email. When I submit my form it stores all the details in a database. And also all the submissions of form I have displayed on the different page. Now I want to update data of each row as according to the user, which row he selects.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

No code provided... but you would need to pass the record id to the form builder as an argument and fetch the record from the database.

At a basic level:

```
// the caller
$form = drupal_get_form('myform', $record_id);

// in the form builder...
function myform($form, &$form_state, $record_id) {
  // db query the table for that record id
  // populate form default values if record found

  // example
  $form['email']['#default_value'] = $query_result ? $query_result['email'] : NULL;
}
```

Although, if you have no unique primary key, this could be next to impossible to select the proper row (knowing nothing more about your requirements).

How are you preventing duplicates? How would you know what row to select? Are you preventing more than one email per nid submission? That would be up to you to figure out, I suppose.

You could also pass the record id as a URL argument and pass that along to the form builder callback, but this would not limit it to the user who *should* be able to edit it (unless you build in access checks etc). That means anyone could just change the url argument and load up another record.

In any case, the code above should get you started.